# Apache Beam does not trigger early repeatedly for session windows on google dataflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The following pipeline fires early after each element when running locally using DirectRunner, but there are no early triggers when running on google cloud dataflow. On dataflow it triggers only after the session window has closed.

```
( p
        | 'read'   >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription = 'projects/xxx/subscriptions/xxx-sub')
        | 'json'   >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
        | 'kv'     >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['id'], x['amount']))
        | 'window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(15*60), trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1)), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING)
        | 'group'  >> beam.GroupByKey()
        | 'log'    >> beam.Map(lambda x: logging.info(x))
)
```

I tried it using Apache Beam 2.23 and 2.28. According to the compatibility matrix, session windows and triggers are fully supported on dataflow. It also fires early when using a fixed window.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, did you have the chance to open a JIRA issue for beam dataflow-runner?

Comment: Filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11906 for this, @YichiZhang

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but it seems that the early trigger works and it fires every time new input comes. Though output seems not matching the desired accumulation mode. Do you mind elaborates more on what is your expected output and what is showing on your dataflow job?

Comment: Thanks for creating a ticket. It fires locally after each input and accumulates the values. 

INFO:root:('123', [10020.3])
INFO:root:('123', [10020.3, 10020.3])
INFO:root:('123', [10020.3, 10020.3, 10020.3])

But on dataflow it fires only after the session gap.

Comment: After a second try on dataflow, you are right, it fires, but the accumulation does not work! "('123', [10020.3])"
"('123', [10020.3])"
"('123', [10020.3])"

Comment: It accumulates only after the session has closed. "('123', [10020.3, 10020.3, 10020.3])"

Comment: The issue seems to be with the runner backend, we'll track and get it fixed asap.